# NHibernate Mapping: Simple Join on a Foreign Key

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

#### The Tables

```
Currencies
----------
CurrencyId INT IDENTITY PK
IsoCode4217 CHAR(3) -- "USD", "GBP", "EUR", etc

Users
----------
UserId INT IDENTITY PK
CurrencyId FK REFERENCES Currencies (CurrencyId)
```

#### The Mapping

The current application has a `Currency` object that needs the `IsoCode4217` value. A `Currency` is not an entity in this application, it's its own weird hard-coded thing where I need to pass the `IsoCode4217` value to a static function and get a `Currency` instance back. The database `Currencies` table is more of an enumeration table. So I figured I'd just implement an `IUserType` and off I'll go, but this does not work as I expect:

```
[hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"]
  [class
    name="BlahBlah.UserProfile, BlahBlah.Model"
    schema="Core"
    table="Users"
    lazy="false"]
    [id name="Identity" access="field.camelcase" column="UserId"]
      [generator class="native" /]
    [/id]
    [join
      schema="Core"
      table="Currencies" 
      fetch="join"]
      [key column="CurrencyId" property-ref="Currency" /]
      [property
        name="Currency"
        column="IsoCode4217" 
        type="BlahBlah.CurrencyUserType, BlahBlah.Model" /]
    [/join]
  [/class]
[/hibernate-mapping]
```

(I changed the angle brackets to regular brackets as I don't feel like thinking about what this little Markdown editor is going to do.)

#### The Ugly

The SQL that I would expect is

```
SELECT
  u.UserId,
  c.IsoCode4217
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN Currencies AS c
   ON u.CurrencyId = c.CurrencyId
```

but instead NHibernate stubbornly gives me

```
SELECT
  u.UserId,
  c.IsoCode4217
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN Currencies AS c
  ON u.UserId = c.CurrencyId -- DANG IT!
```

Is this really not supported, or am I overlooking something obvious? Is it possible to just "loop in" an extra column from another table for the purpose of a single entity's mapping?

Thanks!

Comment: What version of NH are you using?

Comment: I'm using NHibernate-2.1.0.CR1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join mappings are a PITA! The problem here is that Hibernate expects a join mapping to map from a Parent table to a Child table, whereas you're joining from the child table to the parent table.

Essentially, join mappings were designed to make it easy to join on tables that have a one-to-one relationship and where the parent table is joining to a child table.

I think in your situation you want to have a many-to-one mapping rather than a join

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, that's what I thought. But would I be correct in assuming that I can't have a many-to-one mapping work with an IUserType? I really don't want Currency as a persistable entity, I want the three-letter code so I can call Currency.GetCurrency() on this third-party-provided Currency object.

My thinking is I'm going to have to wrap that Currency object with my own type. Blech.